# $x^2 + y^5 = 2015^{17}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I've got stuck at this problem, I don't know how to approach it.

> Prove that the equation doesn't
>   have any integer solutions for $$x^2 + y^5 =  2015^{17}$$

I've thought about Fermat's little theorem but it didn't helped.
Just a hint would be really  appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: try it mod $11$.........

Comment: Man ... now I have to figure out why that's a good hint ...

Comment: You are not alone @John dude

Comment: What are the possible values of $x^2$ and of $y^5$ mod $11$?  What is $2015^{17} \mod 11$?

Comment: Based on your hint, this is how I did: $2015^{17} = 2015^{11} * 2015^6$. $2015^{11} \equiv 2015 \equiv 2 \pmod n$ (fermat). Then, verifying the rests mod $11$ for the first 11 squares we get $\{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9\}$. So, $y\equiv \{2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9\}\pmod 5$ - impossible because $y^5\equiv  \{1,10\}\pmod {11} $.

Comment: But how did you got the idea to do it mod $11$?

Comment: It's often worthwhile trying problems such as this mod small primes.  $11$ has a chance because (thanks to Fermat) $y^{10}$ can only be $0$ or $1$ mod $11$, and thus $y^{5}$ only $0, 1, 10$.